# How to merge tuples into pairs and then turn into a string?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I have two tuples

```
var.sqlserver_privateIP
var.sqlserver_decrypted
```

These each contain multiple values that should be paired. Example,
var.sqlserver_privateIP[0] & var.sqlserver_decrypted[0]
var.sqlserver_privateIP[1] & var.sqlserver_decrypted[1]

From there I would like to run a local-exec provisioner to write the variable to a txt file. Here is what I have right now.

```
locals {
  conns = join("\n", concat(var.sqlserver_privateIP, var.sqlserver_decrypted))
}
resource "null_resource" "guac_setup" {
  triggers = {
    "version" = timestamp()
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo '${local.conns}' >> ${path.module}/private_ips.txt"

    interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
  }
}
```

The issue is that the above doesn't pair the values as I need. The current output to private_ips.txt looks like this *(note it's actually the the values of each)*

```
var.sqlserver_privateIP[0] 
var.sqlserver_privateIP[1]
var.sqlserver_decrypted[0]
var.sqlserver_decrypted[1]
```

This is what I need the private_ips.txt to look like

```
*Connection*
var.sqlserver_privateIP[0] 
var.sqlserver_decrypted[0]

*Connection*
var.sqlserver_privateIP[1]
var.sqlserver_decrypted[1]
```

I think I need to have two for loops (one nested) and then use a join function, but I've been running into issues with syntax so im not exactly sure on the logic.

Comment: What are the actual values of `sqlserver_privateIP` and `sqlserver_decrypted`?

Comment: You could both fix this and make it easier with the `local_file` resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that either the value of `var.sqlserver_privateIP` or `var.sqlserver_decrypted` are always unique, there is a nice solution using [zipmap](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/zipmap), but this should do the trick just as well.

*note: I am using locals in place of variables, but modify as required.*

#### main.tf

```
locals {
  sqlserver_privateIP = [ # var.sqlserver_privateIP
    "10.0.0.10",
    "10.0.0.20",
  ]

  sqlserver_decrypted = [ # var.sqlserver_decrypted
    "foo",
    "bar"
  ]

  connections = [for i in range(length(local.sqlserver_privateIP)) : {
    ip        = local.sqlserver_privateIP[i]
    decrypted = local.sqlserver_decrypted[i]
  }]
}

output "file_contents" {
  value = templatefile(
    "${path.module}/private_idps.txt.tftpl",
    { connections = local.connections }
  )
}
```

#### private_idps.txt.tftpl

```
%{ for c in connections ~}
*Connection*
${c.ip}
${c.decrypted}

%{ endfor ~}
```

So what you do is generate a list of maps, each containing the values you want to pass to a [templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile). Then, you just iterate over this using [template directives](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/strings#directives).

That gives an output I believe you seek.

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + file_contents = <<-EOT
        *Connection*
        10.0.0.10
        foo

        *Connection*
        10.0.0.20
        bar

    EOT
```

Just write that to a [local_file](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/resources/file) and you're off to the races.

---

You can also use [String Templates](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/strings#string-templates) with [Heredoc](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/strings#heredoc-strings) or [Indented Heredoc](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/strings#indented-heredocs). See here:

```
locals {
  sqlserver_privateIP = [ # var.sqlserver_privateIP
    "10.0.0.10",
    "10.0.0.20",
  ]

  sqlserver_decrypted = [ # var.sqlserver_decrypted
    "foo",
    "bar"
  ]

  connections = [for i in range(length(local.sqlserver_privateIP)) : {
    ip        = local.sqlserver_privateIP[i]
    decrypted = local.sqlserver_decrypted[i]
  }]

  tmpl = <<-EOT
    %{for c in local.connections~}*Connection*
    ${c.ip}
    ${c.decrypted}

    %{endfor~}
  EOT
}

output "file_contents" {
  value = local.tmpl
}
```

which gives:

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + file_contents = <<-EOT
        *Connection*
        10.0.0.10
        foo
        
        *Connection*
        10.0.0.20
        bar
        
    EOT
```

Comment: that template file is pretty neat! I got it to work, I just used local file instead of output. However, I am curious if there is a way to implement that template file code within the local variable itself?

Comment: @Almighty: Definitely, see the addendum.

Comment: That's so badass lol. Thanks!!